# How to round dates to week starts in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a DataFrame with a date column. How can I map each date `d` to the start day of the week containing `d`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Date'].dt.dayofweek, unit='d')
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have dates, the accepted answer won't work (at least for me). If you have `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` objects use this instead:

```
df["week_start"] = pd.to_datetime(["timestamp_col"]).dt.to_period('W-SUN').dt.start_time
```

GH discussion on it [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15303)

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative approach for calculating beginning of the week series by using convenience method `pd.DateOffset(weekday=0,weeks=1)`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2016-10-01','2016-10-31')})
df['BeginWeek']=np.where(df.date.dt.weekday==0, # offset on Non Mondays only
                         df['date'], 
                         df['date']-np.timedelta64(1,'W')), 
                         )
```

Thanks to [ribitskyib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2243714/ribitskiyb) `np.where` was added to pick current Monday when date is already Monday. Confirmation that the above works now:

[image]

Some additional ideas provided by others:

Here is a quick list of days of the week:

```
df['BeginWeek'].dt.strftime("%a").unique() 
array(['Mon'], dtype=object)
```

and the days in the original column are:

```
df['date'].dt.strftime("%a").unique()
array(['Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: It gives incorrect (in the context of the question) result if the date is already Monday -- it shifts it back to Monday of the previous week

`pd.Timestamp('2019-10-07') - pd.DateOffset(weekday=0, weeks=1)`
gives `Timestamp('2019-09-30 00:00:00')`